# TextSwitcher without button click

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi could anyone please help me as I am new to android studio development and need help. I have created a textswitcher with a button click, however I want to add some amendments such as when the user makes contact or swipes the screen it swipes to the next text instead of using a button on click method. Please can you advise?.

Java File

```
public class NationalMediaMuseum extends Activity
{
    private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;
    Button btnNext;

    // Array of String to Show In TextSwitcher
    String textToShow[]={"Main HeadLine","Hello World ","Hello Eeveryone","New Articles","Business News","What IS New"};
    int messageCount=textToShow.length;
    // to keep current Index of text
    int currentIndex=-1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_national_media_museum);

        // get The references
        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);

        // Set the ViewFactory of the TextSwitcher that will create TextView object when asked
        mSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {

            public View makeView() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // create new textView and set the properties like clolr, size etc
                TextView myText = new TextView(NationalMediaMuseum.this);
                myText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                myText.setTextSize(36);
                myText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                return myText;
            }
        });

        // Declare the in and out animations and initialize them
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

        // set the animation type of textSwitcher
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);

        // ClickListener for NEXT button
        // When clicked on Button TextSwitcher will switch between texts
        // The current Text will go OUT and next text will come in with specified animation
        btnNext.setonclickListener(new View.onclickListener() {

            public void onclick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                currentIndex++;
                // If index reaches maximum reset it
                if (currentIndex == messageCount)
                    currentIndex = 0;
                mSwitcher.setText(textToShow[currentIndex]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

XML Fiile

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#0d47a1" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_weight="0.32"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logonew" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/logo1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="801dp"
        android:background="#64b5f6"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/textwelcome"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/uname"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textwelcome"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/logout" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="LOGOUT"
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:background="#0d47a1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Museum And Theatres Category"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textwelcome"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/logout" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:id="@+id/nxtbtn"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:background="#0d47a1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="BACK"
            android:id="@+id/bkebtn"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:background="#0d47a1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nxtbtn"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:id="@+id/hmebtn"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:background="#0d47a1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textSwitcher"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:background="#0d47a1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textSwitcher"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hmebtn"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hmebtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Personally I have never used text switcher and I do not really know how it works. However, if you are stuck and find no way of solving your issue; I would say you should use viewpager. It does exactly what you want. If you need help in viewpager just respond to my comment and I will be more than happy to assist.

Comment: A `TextSwitcher` performs the animation whenever you call `setText()`. What you probably want to do is to have a look at gestures (https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) and when you detect a gesture you're interested in, simply change the text. The rest will be automatically taken care of.

Comment: Miriana Itani could you please assist me with ViewPager as I have never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the android developer page giving an over view on how to use a ViewPager which should do exactly what you are looking for.  This is the way I have done it in my applications previously.  [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)